# Identify AD Group Type: Distribution Group or Security Group

Tags: active-directory, ldap, .net, windows

How do I know whether a AD group is a Distribution Group or Security Group? 
Note: I am an ordinary user. I do not have permission to run power shell scripts. Any way to identify using User Interface that does not require admin permissions?

Comment: Which "User Interface" are you referring to? Do you have access to the Active Directory Users and Computers interface? If not, how would you look at a list of groups that you'd like to know this about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can assign the group permissions to a folder in your home directory using Windows Explorer, it is a security group.

Answer (score 1):

You can view domain properties as a normal user even though you have no permissions to change anything.

Just install the [Windows Admin Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=7887) and open Active Directory Users and Computers from the Administrative Tools menu.